# Connection to database cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin, maui

I added sqlite-net-plc and created `Database` class:

```
public class Database
{
    public Database()
    {
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "databaseTest.db3");

        Connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        Connection.CreateTableAsync<User>().Wait();
    }

    public SQLiteAsyncConnection Connection { get; set; }
}
```

This works with Android applications. However, when I run this through an IOS simulator with an active Mac connection I get following error:

> The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.

I believe connection to SQLite database cannot be resolved but why?

Comment: Do you have any inner exception?

Comment: Nope. This is why I'm confused

Comment: For questions about maui, you can go to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues.

Comment: Im not sure if it is a MAUI issue or a SQLite/Ios one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered here on github: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3211

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing the same exception on both iOS and Android after adding sqlite-net-pcl to the stock MAUI test app until I explicitly added the https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green/2.0.7 package to the project.

I see that on September 7 the "raw" package author noted that he had work to do: https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/discussions/449#discussioncomment-1282643

sqlite-net-pcl depends on version 2.0.4 of the "raw" nuget which is over a year old.  Maybe 2.0.7 fixed something relevant for iOS? I see some Apple-specific commits at https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/commits/master in that timeframe.

Maybe you already had a newer version installed that had fixes for Android, but not iOS?

Answer (score 2):

I am developing .NET Maui app on .NET7 and was having this issue. Updating the package `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green` to the latest 2.1.2 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me to get iOS to work:

Install these packages

```
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.0" />
```

Then change `Platforms.iOS.AppDelegate.cs` to

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate
{
    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        raw.SetProvider(new SQLite3Provider_sqlite3());
        return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
    }
}
```